# Re-purposing RestComm

Tags: java, restcomm

All,

Apparently, RestComm has taken up the Mobicents project, which I worked with a bit a few years ago.  I am in the throws of assessing as to whether RestComm is suitable for my new project and am looking to confirm what I have read so far.  Clearly, RestComm is oriented toward telephony.  But I see that it appears to still rely on the JAIN/SLEE api and that it supports an HTTP resource adapter.

Question:
Can I configure RestComm with only the HTTP RA and productively implement my services using the SBBs?

I don't need VOIP at this juncture but I do like the robust, low latency, acid transactions, and asynchronous nature for my project. My inputs and outputs are medium to large XML/JSON documents.

Any insights will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mobicents was rebranded to Restcomm recently, you can read more on this at http://www.telestax.com/restcomm-moves-beyond-mobicents/

The Restcomm Platform is comprised of 3 main parts as can be seen on the diagram at http://documentation.telestax.com/

- The Restcomm Web, iOS and Android SDKs and Clients which allows you to embed Communications as a feature in your Web, iOS and Android Native Applications
- The Restcomm-Connect, which is an API Exposure layer allowing Web developers to embed Communications as a Feature without having to know anything about telecommunications. You can read Restcomm Connect Tutorials to learn more on how to build powerful apps or leanr to master the platform.
- The Restcomm Core which is the core of the Restcomm Communications Platform and powers Restcomm-Connect. It contains all the necessary low level telecommunications stacks, servers and standalone components allowing you to write powerful and scalable telecommunications applications that interconnect with core network telecommunications elements such as Core IN SS7 Networks or IMS Core Network/EPC for newer generation networks

  - Restcomm SIP Servlets / SIP - IMS - LTE - WebRTC Application Server
  - Restcomm JAIN SLEE Service Delivery Platform
  - Restcomm Media Server
  - Restcomm SMSC
  - Restcomm USSD Gateway
  - Restcomm GMLC GeoLocation Server
  - Restcomm jSS7 Stack
  - Restcomm JAIN SIP Stack
  - Restcomm jDiameter
  - Restcomm Load Balancer

JAIN SLEE and the HTTP Resource Adaptor is still part of the platform and you can get it from https://github.com/RestComm/jain-slee. It can be used without any relation to Telco/VoIP indeed.